# UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey always null - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, appdelegate, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an iOS application which uses local notifications. When the app is running in the background or is active, I use the `application didReceiveLocalNotification` methods and that works great. But when the app is closed (not running in the background), I use the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method to control what happens when the notification is handled.

However, the problem I have is that the notification is always `(null)` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Here is my code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Register the app for local notifcations.

    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }

    // Setup the local notification check.
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    //UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"options" message:notification delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    //[alertView show];

    // Check if a notifcation has been received.

    if (notification) {

        // Run the notifcation.
        [self.myViewController run_notifcation:[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"notification_id"]];
    }

    // Ensure the notifcation badge number is hidden.
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    return YES;
}
```

Am I missing something here? I have asked the user for permission first and have the correct code to get the notification object. My app is built for iOS 9 and higher only.

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: How did you find out that the notification is always `null`? Are you running app from Xcode in debug mode? By default there is no notification to start with

Comment: @Azat I tried showing the notification object in a uialertview.

Comment: When the app is not running in the background and if the user taps on the notification, then the app would be launched and the notification would have value. Ensure user taps on notification

Comment: Pls make sure the user taps on the notification, also print the `launchOptions` dictionary to see if there is any value

Comment: @user1046037 Could it be because my code is calling a method from ```self.myViewController``` which at that point of the app hasn't been loaded yet?

Comment: No, I feel you have tapped on a remote notification but you are checking for local notification

Comment: If it is a remote notification then use `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` instead of 
`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`

Comment: @user1046037 Not its not a remote notification, I am using local notifications only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107524/discussion-between-user1046037-and-supertecnoboff).

Comment: @user1046037 Hey your solution (the one from the chat group - putting my method call in a main thread block) worked! If you put it as an answer, I will be happy to tick it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display the value `launchOptions` in an alert view to see if there is any value.

If the value is not nil, then probably your UI code gets executed in the background thread.

Ensure all UI code is executed in the main thread as shown below:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
//self doSomething (UI Code)
});
```

This is important when you use asynchronous calls in your app.

Answer (score -1):

Implement your code in `applicationWillTerminate` rather than `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Because when the app terminated then execute the `applicationWillTerminate` method.

```
 func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
     // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
 }
```

Comment: I don't see how that will fix the problem, I am trying to call a method when then app has been opened. I really don't think this will solve my problem.